# JS - Compare first row to other rows in table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm a completely newbie and looking for help.

Given the following table:

```
<table id="table">
 <thead>
  # FIRST ROW
  <tr>
   <th>Apple</th>
   <th>Pizza</th>
   <th>Eggs</th>
 </tr>
 <tbody>
 # SECOND ROW 
 <tr>
  <td>Apple</td>   --> should end with 'success' class
  <td>Juice</td>
  <td>Lettuce</td>
  <td>Oranges</td>
  <td>Eggs</td>    --> should end with 'success' class
 </tr>
 # THIRD ROW
 <tr>
  <td>Pizza</td>   --> should end with 'success' class
  <td>Chicken</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to add class '*success*' to every **td** in *SECOND* and *THIRD* rows whenever it matches any **td** in *FIRST* row (and only in FIRST ROW).

For now I came up with adding `<td>` values of first row to array and I'm not sure what steps should I take next (*filter*? *for loop* and '===' comparison?):

```
function myFunction() {
 var tHeadersValues = [];
 var tHeaders = document.getElementById("table").rows[0].cells;

 for (var i = 0; i < tHeaders.length; i++) {
  tHeadersValues.push(tHeaders[i].textContent);
 }

 return tHeadersValues;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys(tHeaders).map(key => tHeaders[key].textContent)` transforms the td objects to an array with the containing text. The rest is straight forward:

```js
function toValues(tHeaders) {
  return Object.keys(tHeaders).map(function(key){ 
      return tHeaders[key].textContent;
  });
}

function myFunction() {
    var rows = document.getElementById("results-table").rows;
    var tHeadersValues = toValues(rows[0].cells);
    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var rowCells = rows[i].cells;
        var values = toValues(rowCells);
        for(var j=0;j<values.length;j++) {
          if(values[j].length > 0 && tHeadersValues.indexOf(values[j]) > -1) {
              rowCells[j].className = "success";
          }
        }
    }
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<style>  
.success {
    background-color: green;  
}
</style>
<table id="results-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Apple</th>
        <th>Pizza</th>
        <th>Eggs</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Juice</td>
        <td>Lettuce</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
        <td>Eggs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pizza</td>
        <td>Chicken</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You're great :) Is it possible to add *success* class also to first rows' values? Reversing the function should work but I think it's overdo.

Comment: Sorry, what do you want to do? Adding the success-class to all td elements of the first row?

Comment: First row could contain td elements that don't match any td values in other rows - it'd be nice to have highlighted tds that match :)

Comment: `tHeadersValues.indexOf(values[j])` gives you the index to the matching cell in the first row. use this index to select a cell of the first row and set the class `rows[0].cells[matchIndex].className='success'`. This call would be happen more often than necessary, but i think this should not lead to performance issues, if the table is not very big.

Comment: Arrow functions do not work in many browsers including last safari

Comment: @user104317 yes, I changed the example

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunc(){
  var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  var hds = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
  for(var i=0; i<tds.length; i++) {
    var tdContent = tds[i].innerHTML;
    if(tdContent.length > 0){
        for(var j = 0; j<hds.length; j++) {
          if(tdContent === hds[j].innerHTML) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].className = "success";
          }
        }
    }  
  }
}
myFunc();
```

```html
<style>
    .success {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
<table id="results-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Apple</th>
        <th>Pizza</th>
        <th>Eggs</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Juice</td>
        <td>Lettuce</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
        <td>Eggs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pizza</td>
        <td>Chicken</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```